# Automate saving/email html page daily

Tags: download, automation, html

I am looking for ideas on how to do this
I have an intranet site , lets call it 
http://intranet/update.html

if I do this manually I would
1. go to the site http://intranet/update.html 
2. click save as HTML to my desktop , give it a name , for example updateJan2.html

now I want to do this daily automatically. so in the end i will have 
updateJan2.html
updateJan3.html
updateJan4.html
ect ...


the saving to my desktop is optional. it can be email to me as well. anything that will 
allow me to automatically save this page daily.

thank you and I appreciate the input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating my own vb.net exe and task scheduler. 
the exe will load the webpage on a vb.net webBrowser control and save it as HTML.
then task scheduler just need to run the exe daily

Thank you